# Send a custom signal to curreng Golang process

Tags: http, go, server, signals, reload

I'm creating a HTTP server using Go. And whenever I work on a database maintenance, I want the server to redirect all the traffic to "current working on maintenance" page.

Currently, this is done by secret admin page (eg. http://myhome/secret) but I'm wondering if this can be done with signal -similar to TERM signal, but temporarily redirect rather than actually terminate the process.

Eg.

```
/home/myhome> nohup startServer &
... 
/home/myhome> changeMyServerStatus "maintenance"
```

I assume there will be two executable.. "startServer" and "changeMyServerStatus"

So, this is similar to a service. (like reload) But, is this possible? If so, can you give me some hint please?

Thank you

Comment: It's possible, but signals lack granularity. Why not just have an auth route that can control the temporary redirect? That way you know the state of the server. Sending signals is flying blind - as there's no return code to indicate the signal was received. Plus a http route can be invoked remotely - signals require (Root) local access.

Comment: What about using SIGHUP?

Comment: I'd recommend that you use a middleware, and redirect all requests to that page in the right conditions. Would probably not need signals. Use an authenticated endpoint to change the status and it should be fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As noted in the comments, signals may not be the best way to accomplish this. I’m assuming that you do want signals nonetheless.

You can use the [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html) user signals: `SIGUSR1` to enable maintenance and `SIGUSR2` to disable it.

Use [`os/signal`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/signal/) to get notified of these signals and update program state:

```
// Brief example code. Real code might be structured differently
// (perhaps pack up maint and http.Server in one type MyServer).

var maint uint32 // atomic: 1 if in maintenance mode

func handleMaintSignals() {
    ch := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    go func() { // FIXME: use Server.RegisterOnShutdown to terminate this
        for sig := range ch {
            switch sig { // FIXME: add logging
            case syscall.SIGUSR1:
                atomic.StoreUint32(&maint, 1)
            case syscall.SIGUSR2:
                atomic.StoreUint32(&maint, 0)
            }
        }
    }()
    signal.Notify(ch, syscall.SIGUSR1, syscall.SIGUSR2)
}
```

Have a middleware look at that state and respond accordingly:

```
func withMaint(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if atomic.LoadUint32(&maint) == 1 {
            http.Error(w, "Down for maintenance", http.StatusServiceUnavailable)
            return
        }
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

You can apply this middleware on a per-route basis, or directly to the server’s [root handler](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server.Handler):

```
func main() {
    handleMaintSignals()
    srv := http.Server{
        Addr:    ":17990",
        Handler: withMaint(http.DefaultServeMux),
    }
    srv.ListenAndServe()
}
```

You don’t need a second executable like `changeMyServerStatus`. Use your operating system’s tools to send signals, such as [pkill](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/pkill.1.html):

```
$ nohup myserver &

$ curl http://localhost:17990/
404 page not found

$ pkill -USR1 myserver

$ curl http://localhost:17990/
Down for maintenance

$ pkill -USR2 myserver

$ curl http://localhost:17990/
404 page not found
```

But manually juggling `nohup` and `pkill` is tedious and error-prone. Instead, use a service manager such as [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) to manage your process. Systemd lets you send arbitrary signals with [`systemctl kill`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/systemctl.1.html):

```
systemctl kill -s SIGUSR1 myserver
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Well, it's part of learning for me rather trying to have a production ready code :) Thank you again!